# Weird headers c++

Tags: c++

On `A.h` i do not have to `#include` anything or use namespace for anything.

On the other header, `B.h` i have to include `vector` and `using namespace std`. Both of this headers are not linked. Seems to be a file problem. When i copy the contents of `A.h` (without any problems) to `B.h`, i still get a compiler error saying `string` is not a type name and `vector` is not a template although the compiler did not state anything when the same content was on `A.h`. I am coding c++ on visual studio. What is going on?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org).  Also please do not use `using namespace std;` in a header file.  further reading: [Why is “using namespace std” in C++ considered bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: yeah i did not use. I am saying. The compiler is giving me problems

Comment: How can we tell you what the problem could be without seeing the code the compiler is trying to compile?

Comment: @user859385 compiler doesn't *give you problems*. Your program is (probably) ill formed and the compiler tells you what's wrong with it. If you don't understand what the compiler says, then you can show us a [mcve] and we can explain it to you.

Comment: Header files are usually not compiled. They are always included (i.e. expanded) in compilation units. Those compilation units may change the environment for the header.

Comment: Just an idea, but is it possible that there are include files that are always included before A.h and not before B.h.  Normally, you should always include (or declare) what you need in a header file, so actually B.h is the one without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your header files should have `#include <string>` and `#include <vector>` among their first few lines.  Then when you refer to those types either in your program or in the header file, I would recommend referring to `std::string` and `std::vector`. Using qualified references like that is the preferred alternative to `using namespace std`, as @NathanOliver pointed out.

Comment: IMHO, header files should only `#include` header files *to resolve symbols in the header file*.  Use `#include` in source files to resolve symbols in the source file.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I agree. I think my answer assumed the context that the header file in question did declare objects of top `string` and `vector`.